# Get the co-ordinates of a Form

Tags: c#, forms, resize, height, width

I was wondering, how do you get the co-ordinates of a form?

I have an application which currently has a button. This button is ***randomly*** re-positioned every 1 second. However, I want this button to always be re-positioned within the Form - rather than going outside of the bounds of the form. So, i was thinking i should find the bounds of the form and use that in order to make sure the button is always within the bounds of the form. How do i get the height and width of the form?

I have the following code working (But the user's screen size is not what i want):

```
int screenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
int screenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
```

Shouldn`t this code work?

```
int xPosition = position.X;
int yPosition = position.Y; 
int num = random.Next(screenHeight);
int num1 = random.Next(screenWidth);

Point templocation;
templocation = new Point(num1, num);


ClickMe.Location = templocation;
templocation.X = num1;
templocation.Y = num;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. i've viewed this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resize(v=vs.71).aspx but the line  "Control control = (Control)sender;" generates an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your update here is the new answer:

When positioning your button you have to make sure to not exceed the forms boundaries. So your button's left position is somewhere between

```
int leftMin = 0;
int leftMax = myForm.ClientSize.Width - myButton.Width;
```

as for the button's top position

```
int topMin = 0;
int topMax = myForm.ClientSize.Height - myButton.Height;
```

So for your example:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.Next(0, ClientSize.Width - button1.Width);
    int y = random.Next(0, ClientSize.Height - button1.Height);
    button1.Location = new Point(x, y);
}
```

---

Old answer ...

If you're looking for the position of the current form on screen:

```
int xPosition = this.Location.X;    
int yPosition = this.Location.Y;
```

or

```
Point position = this.Location;
```

Although Location will be "0, 0" inside the forms constructor.

Comment: Hmmm..... i guess this gets the initial size of the screen? Basically i have a timer which changes the position of the button. But i want the button to always be within the bounds of the form screen size. It seems when i use this that the button stays in the general area prior to the form being expanded in size...

Comment: Ok, I really think you should edit your original question to tell everyone exactly what you're trying to achieve. Right now it looks like you're messing up the terms "Form", "Button", "Position", "Size" and like there is a profound misunderstanding of how OOP regarding Windows Forms works ...

Comment: I donno what's going on... if the form is made larger.. the button just never moves into the extended area of the form... :S your answer makes complete sense though..

Answer (score 0):

Use the form's [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx) (which is of Type Point):

```
this.Location
```

(use this instead of `Form1`)

Also:

```
this.Height
this.Width
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Form.Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms159414.aspx) property gives you *"The Point that represents the upper-left corner of the Form in screen coordinates."*

Comment: i get strange errors when i try to use this.... so i'm not quite sure what to do about that... "Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Windows.Forms.Form.Location.get'
"

Comment: @BlueButtons: You cannot write `Form.Location` in your code, because this is the syntax to access a static property (or class property). You need an instance of the `Form` class to access this property. You already have an instance in your code. From the code _inside your form class_ you can access the properties by typing `this.Location`. From code outside your class you need a `Form` variable to access the properties - e.g. something that is passed to a method: `void foo(Form myForm) { Point location = myForm.Location; }`. Maybe you should read a book about Object-oriented programming...

Comment: Hmm.... okay, so i understand this now. However, it appears as if when the form is being expanded, it isn't being detected? I have a button that i always want to have re-positioning itself within the bounds of the form. However, the button simply moves within the bounds of the original form size... what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

For width and height, use

```
form.Size.Width
form.Size.Height
```

Comment: hmm i've tried this and for some reason it's not capturing the actual size of the form....

Comment: What is it capturing, then? How did you call it?